# Django Form Saving, but NOT Redirecting

Tags: django, forms, redirect, response.redirect, django-forms

Basis: I am trying to display a forms information with a new unique url as well as view upon submission. The form is currently saving to the database, but not redirection to the new url or view. Below I've posted both the views.py as well as the urls.py. If you need to see anything else please let me know.

Note: This is based off of a ModelForm and I am somewhat of a beginner to Django.

Thanks in advance!

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^letter/testing/$', 'letter.views.letter'),
url(r'^letter/testing/(?P<pk>\d+)/$','letter.views.submission'),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

)

views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from letter.forms import LetterForm
from letter.models import Letter

def submission(request, pk):
    submission = get_object_or_404(Letter, pk=int(pk))
    return render_to_response('post.html', {'submission':submission})

def letter(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    letter = LetterForm(request.POST)

    if letter.is_valid():
        try: 
            new_letter = letter.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/letter/testing/%d/' % new_letter.pk)
        except:
            pass        

else:
    letter = LetterForm()

return render_to_response('letter.html',
        {'letter':letter},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

ANSWER:
Needed to remove the try/except parameters under if letter.is_valid()

Thank you @mattg!

Comment: Why do you have the try/except block under letter.is_valid?

Comment: @mattg I ran through a tutorial and this is how they presented it. Is this not the correct way?

Comment: It seems pretty odd to have a blanket except block that's just ignored.  What happens if you remove the try/except block and just save the letter and redirect?

Comment: @mattg I just tried that and it semi-worked. I am not getting this error "global name 'HttpResponseRedict' is not defined"

Comment: @mattg there was a typo... should be 'HttpResponseRedirect' not HttpResponseRedict. It's working now! Thanks, man.

Comment: That's the problem with blanket except blocks in python - they hide name and syntax errors, too.  Glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to remove the `try` and `except` parameters under `if letter.is_valid()`